# ErrorException in Guard.php line 453

Tags: laravel

Getting error when trying to login

```
    $set_user = DB::table('v_user_branch')
                ->select('id', 'company_information_id')
                ->where('users_id','=',$user->id)
                ->where('default_branch','=',1);
                ->get()[0];

    session()->put('company_information_id', $set_user->company_information_id);
    session()->put('branch_id',$set_user->id);
```

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaM1h.png)

[code image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpOy.png)

Comment: Try first() replace get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$set_user = DB::table('v_user_branch')
                ->select('id', 'company_information_id')
                ->where('users_id','=',$user->id)
                ->where('default_branch','=',1);
                ->first();
```

get() function returns a collection; not an array. If you want only the first instance then use first() method.

Comment: sorry got result , in my  view table(v_user_branch ) no data was available.

Comment: which you mention , it's also working. Thank You. @nabil-farhan